# ajax PHP saves inconsistant results to Db

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please see following code:

When I go to edit data, the returned saved data for one field 'status' can be saved correctly or sometimes some letters are stripped out when saved.
In the status field there are three possible values 'credit', 'debit' or 'visa'.
'debit' and 'visa' values are returned and saved correctly but SOME credit values are saved are simply as 'cr' even though the text box displays 'credit' before save...even clearing field and typing in 'credit' before save doesnt help..

```
CurrentPage.EditItem = function(id) {
if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    console.log("DetailPage :: edit");
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var itemm = $("#itemm").val();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var status = $("#status").val();
    var Uid = localStorage.getItem("Uid");
    //formData = {
     //   UId: sessionStorage.userId,
       // itemm: $("#name").val(),
       // amount: $("#amount").val(),
       // status: $("#status").val(),
      // }
     if (itemm == "") {
        alert("Please enter item");
    } else if (amount == "") {
        alert("Please enter office amount");
    } else if (status == "") {
        alert("Alert", "Please enter phone status");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://www.mywebsite.com/edit.php',
            data:{'Uid':Uid,'itemm':itemm,'amount':amount,'status':status},
             crossDomain: true, // enable this
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Edit item success");
                window.location.href = "listof.html"    
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Edit user gone wrong");
            }

            });
            }
}
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="car">
    <ul class="view">
        <li >Item:</li>

        <li ><input id="itemm" name="itemm" type="text"></li>

        <li >Amount:</li>

        <li ><input id="amount" name="amount" type="text"></li>

        <li >Status:</li>

        <li ><input id="status" name="status" type="text"></li>


    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="car" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
        <button id="edit" class="btn btn-positive btn-block" onclick="currentPage.EditItem();">EDIT ITEM</button>
   </div>
   <div class="car" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
        <button class="btn btn-negative btn-block" onclick="currentPage.deleteItem();">REMOVE ITEM</button>
```

PHP

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","mxxxxxx","xxxxx89x78x","ccxcxcxcxc_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$itemm_id = $_POST['Uid'];
$itemm_itemm = $_POST['itemm'];
$itemm_amount = $_POST['amount'];
$itemm_status = $_POST['status'];

$qry = "UPDATE balance1 SET itemm = '$itemm_itemm', amount = '$itemm_amount' , status = '$itemm_status' 
WHERE id ='$itemm_id'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record updated";

mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Any thoughts ???

Comment: a) vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) b) provided no details about back-end DB structure c) specifying text/json as the output, then outputting plain text that is most definitely not json d) provided no details about what kind of debugging you've done, like doing `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's arriving at the server

Comment: as @MarcB pointed out, you should really address the problem with the sql injections, as for the question, please post the structure of the table, balance1. +collation and encoding of the table. and fields.

Comment: a) Will resolve for sql injection .. just testing for now 
b) MySQL: id, int. itemm, varchar, Collation utf8_general_ci. amount, int. statuss, varchar, Collation utf8_general_ci. (Only issue is with this field - have changed column name to statuss but no help) 
c) json text was not being used 
d) not 100% how to use var_dump?

Comment: Well I sorted it....

Weird one...

I was using Ripple Emulator ... once I switched back to normal view all was good....really weird..week of my life wasted...

Thanks all..
Maybe I should investigate why ripple was causing this? Hmm